# issue with the opacity

Tags: html, css

am facing a problem with the opacity
i do have a header that have a background image and am trying to do a opacity on that background but not into white color am trying to make it on a black one 
here is the code

```css
/*Start Header*/
.header {
 background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/FzOVLvC.jpg);
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -0-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 opacity: 0.5;
 background-color: #000;
 height: 708px;

}
/*End Header*/
```

```html
<!-- Start Slider -->
 <div class="header">
  <div class="slider">
   <div class="contaner">
    Slider
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
<!-- End Slider -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve your problem by using `rgba` or `hsla` functions. Try to manipulate those lines to see how they work. ;)

```css
#p1 {background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);}   /* red with opacity */
#p2 {background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3);}   /* green with opacity */
#p3 {background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.3);}   /* blue with opacity */

#p1 {background-color: hsla(120, 100%, 50%, 0.3);}   /* green with opacity */
#p2 {background-color: hsla(120, 100%, 75%, 0.3);}   /* light green with opacity */
#p3 {background-color: hsla(120, 100%, 25%, 0.3);}   /* dark green with opacity */
#p4 {background-color: hsla(120, 60%, 70%, 0.3);}    /* pastel green with opacity */
```

Answer (score 0):

Your background color is in rgb and not in rgba. try creating color using rgba() or hsla() functions if you are serious about opacity

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors_legal.asp